# How to use priority in celery task.apply_async

Tags: python, rabbitmq, queue, celery, priority-queue

I have a `test` queue in celery and I have defined a task for it:

```
@celery_app.task(queue='test', ignore_result=True)
def priority_test(priority):
    print(priority)
```

which just print the argument.I want to set the `priority` attribute which is defined [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) for `appy_async`. So, I wrote a `for loop` like this:

```
for i in range(100):
    priority_test.apply_async((i%10,), queue="test", priority=i%10)
```

I excpected to see some result like this:

```
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,309: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 10
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,311: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 10
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,314: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 10
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,317: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 9
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,319: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 9
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,321: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 9
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,323: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 8
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,326: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 8
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,329: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 8
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,332: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 7
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,334: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 7
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,336: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 7
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,341: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 6
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,344: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 6
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,346: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 6
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,349: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 5
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,351: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 5
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,353: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 5
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,355: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 4
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,358: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 4
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,360: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 4
```

means execute the same priorities after each other but it executed them in the normal way:

```
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,309: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 10
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,311: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 9
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,314: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 8
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,317: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 7
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,319: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 6
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,321: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 5
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,323: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 4
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,326: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 3
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,329: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 2
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,332: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 1
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,334: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 10
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,336: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 9
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,341: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 8
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,344: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 7
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,346: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 6
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,349: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 5
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,351: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 4
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,353: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 3
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,355: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 2
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,358: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 1
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,360: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 10
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,362: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 9
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,364: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 8
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,365: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 7
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,367: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 6
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,369: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 5
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,371: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 4
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,373: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 3
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,374: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 2
[2017-12-26 17:21:37,376: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] 1
```

How should I apply `priority` in celery with rabbitmq and what is the `priority` attribute in the doc above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to have `priority` working properly you need to properly configure a couple of settings and you need at least version 3.5.0 of RabbitMQ.

First set the `x-max-priority` of your queue to 10. From the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#rabbitmq-message-priorities) :

```
from kombu import Exchange, Queue

app.conf.task_queues = [
    Queue('tasks', Exchange('tasks'), routing_key='tasks',
          queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 10},
]
```

A default value for all queues can be set using the `task_queue_max_priority` setting:

```
app.conf.task_queue_max_priority = 10
```

Then configure the following settings:

```
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
```

By default the prefetch multiplier is 4, which in your case will cause the first 4 tasks with priority 10, 9, 8 and 7 to be fetched before the other tasks are present in the queue. The `CELERY_ACKS_LATE` setting will cause the tasks to be acknowledged after they have been executed. You can experiment with this setting to see what behaviour you prefer.

Comment: I rejected the suggested edit that wanted to replace `task_queue_max_priority` with `task_default_priority`. The latter is to configure the default priority for every task, which is not asked in the question nor needed for task priorities to work. It is however a setting that can be used in addition to the other tasks if you do not wish to supply a priority for all tasks.